# echo -e is not outputting correctly the result in a file when redirecting to a file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Im running a script to get information of ports on a switch. I need to get the output results on a file instead of seeing the same command running. It reads from a file the ports fine. If I do not redirect to a file I get the right info; but when I redirect to a file I can see only the same command Im running on the switch. lldp-list.txt is a text file with the ports info (3 ports as an example).

What could be wrong? I tried "tee" and "`" with no success. Im missing something

On this line it outputs the results fine:

- echo -e "show lldp neighbor-info $ports | inc Chassis-Desc"

Output:

- Neighbor Chassis-Description   : ArubaOS (MODEL: 205)
- Neighbor Chassis-Description   : ArubaOS (MODEL: 225)
- Neighbor Chassis-Description   : ArubaOS (MODEL: 325)

but when I redirect; I get the following result on the "output.txt" file

```
echo -e "show lldp neighbor-info $ports | inc Chassis-Desc" >> output.txt

show lldp neighbor-info 1/1/1 | inc Chassis-Desc
show lldp neighbor-info 1/1/5 | inc Chassis-Desc
show lldp neighbor-info 1/1/6 | inc Chassis-Desc
```

Here is the code:

```
while IFS= read -r ports; do
echo -e "show lldp neighbor-info $ports | inc Chassis-Desc" >> output.txt
sleep 2
done < lldp-list.txt
```

---

Yes; I need de quotation marks; Its a command that I am executing from the switch via a telnet session. Without the " " the script returns an error. That's why I'm using `echo -e ...` so it sends that command line to the switch via telnet session from the bash script.

As a workaround I use tee and the end of the telnet session line:

```
telnet $MRV_HOST $MRV_PORT | tee output.txt
```

I had to do more parsing with the output file. But I still believe there should be a way to fix the issue Im seeing....

Comment: Hi. It didnt worked with echo -e $(show lldp.......) >> output.txt. But you are right; what I want its to run the command and output the result. In which it works as long as I didnt redirect the output!....  Doenst makes sense to me why didnt worked if I redirect the output. I tried also the ` but maybe im putting it wrong on the line. Tried different options with no lucck

Comment: How are you accessing the switch exactly? I suppose you're running that script on a separate computer, and sending the commands to the switch somehow? How?

Comment: There's no way for us to reproduce the problem, so anything we can offer are just guesses.

Comment: Please look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and make sure to format commands and their output as code so we can understand what you are doing. Also, I added the text you had posted as answer, please [edit] your post and integrate it into the question. I don't quite understand what you wanted to say.

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` is interpreting your command as a string, and outputting that.  From your description, it sounds like you want to run the command and output the result.

Try this:

```
while IFS= read -r ports; do
echo -e $(show lldp neighbor-info $ports | inc Chassis-Desc) >> output.txt
sleep 2
done < lldp-list.txt
```

The quotation marks were changed to `$()` to utilize the shell's [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and `echo` should now output the result of the command instead of the command string.

You do not really need the `echo` or command substitution in this case and could change the script to the following:

```
while IFS= read -r ports; do
show lldp neighbor-info $ports | inc Chassis-Desc >> output.txt
sleep 2
done < lldp-list.txt
```

Comment: [Useless echo](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005): `show lldp .. | inc ... >> output.txt`

Comment: Useless `echo` elaborated on SU: [*What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)